# edit DTS package in sql 2008 management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-8.1, dts

Hi i am trying to edit DTS Package in sql server 2008 management studio, i followed this site [DTS Packages in SQL Server 2005 or 2008 64bit](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/mikedavis/ssis/162/dts-packages-in-sql-server-2005-or-2008-64bit#)

i was able to see it, but now i am getting another error

> sql server 2000 dts designer components are required to edit dts packages. install the special web download, "SQL server 2000 DTS Designer component" to use this feature.

i am using SQL management studio 2008 
my local window is windows 8 64-bit

Comment: So, did you try installing the special web download, "SQL server 2000 DTS Designer component" to use this feature???

Comment: yes i download it, but i found that i cannot find this path
Microsoft SQL Server"\80\Tools\Binn\Resources\1033 i can see only Microsoft SQL Server"\80\Tools\Binn\1033  which mean Resources folder was missing, i tried to created it manually, but it didnt worked

Answer (score 1):

Ideally DTS Packages should be upgraded to SSIS packages as we move from sql 2000 to sql 2005/sql 2008. And one of the good articles which provides information on how to upgrade DTS packages to SSIS package is written by Jason Howell

[Microsoft blog to update sqlserver2000 dts to 2005/2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/07/09/error-sql-server-2000-dts-designer-components-are-required-to-edit-dts-packages-install-the-special-web-download-sql-server-2000-dts-designer-components-to-use-this-feature-microsoft-sqlserver-dtsobjectexplorerui-ssms.aspx)

Some one said that the issue with path :- [Path issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcae9086-4345-4c59-8dd8-9ddeca4edc45/sql-server-2000-dts-designer-components-are-required-to-edit-dts-packages-in-sql-2008?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

http://www.windows-tech.info/15/526346d6af32160c.php

or

Are you migrate or edit dts which is older version?

You have to installed this :-

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11988

or

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e372a9a7-a0b1-43e2-9bc7-b54bd8b252ab/sql-server-2000-dts-tools-web-download?forum=sqlintegrationservices

The reason are:-

1. "You might need the 2000 runtime if you run this as a DTS package as well. I haven't worked with this in 2008, so I'm not sure, but 2005 had a runtime component as well."

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic625890-148-1.aspx

1. "However, if all instances of the SQL Server 2000 relational engine are removed or upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2, the ability to develop DTS packages will no longer exist. The SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup application will install an updated DTS runtime and command-line tools, but no DTS design environment will be available. In this case, you can install the DTS Designer Components via a Web download as part of the Feature Pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - December 2008.  For more DTS-related upgrade information, see Considerations for Upgrading Data Transformation Services in SQL Server 2008 R2 Books Online.

Comment: i donloaded all the component that are needed to work with these did i miss something
SQLServer2005_DTS.msi
SQLServer2005_BC_x64.msi

Comment: What issue you face, after download

Comment: i was able to see the DTS but as i mention above i was not able to open the package